# Calculate hit rate for apache proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

When using apache as a proxy for a number of clients how can I work out the hit rate for the cached items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can calculate the hit ratio by counting the entries in access_log with return code [200](http://www.mccormickfamily.com/become-an-author/56-http-status-codes#200) and [304](http://www.mccormickfamily.com/become-an-author/56-http-status-codes#304).

- 200 => no hit (most of the time)
- 304 => hit (most of the time)

it is not the absolute exact cache hit ratio, but is good enough in most cases.

and some more background [info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html) from apache.